# Is there an Excel Formula which can fill cells with a specific number at a regular interval of rows?

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I am using `Excel 365` and I have a `Table` with 4,182 `rows` (excluding Row 1 which contains the Columns Headers).

I need to add a new column (column L) to this Table with the following logic:

Cell `L2` to Cell `L103` to be filled with `1`, Cell `L104` to Cell `L205` to be filled with `2`, and so on till Cell `L4182`.

The logic here is to fill Column `L` with values `1` to `41` at every interval of `102` rows.

Can this be achieved with an `Excel` formula or may be with `VBA` codes?

Comment: Fill the first 102 rows with `1` then on row 104 input the formula `=L2+1` and drag down to the end of the column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a simple example:

[image]

Formula used in `B2`:

```
=ROUNDUP((ROW()-1)/5,0)
```

Obviously you could change the 5 to 102.

Another option would be to use:

```
=ROUNDUP(COUNTA($B$1:B1)/102,0)
```